# Can I change Wacom Bamboo touch settings?

Tags: touchscreen

I have a Wacom Bamboo Touch tablet connected to my Ubuntu computer, and there are two annoyances:

1. The touchpad-mouse cursor is much too sensitive, making it impossible to click anything.
2. Two-finger touch (scroll) has a delay of ~ half a second before scrolling. How do I remove this?

I've looked around a lot and basically there is no GUI control panel at all. When you enter:

`xsetwacom --list parameters`

You get a lot of parameters that can be changed, but the only thing that seems to relate to touch is turning it on or off:

`xsetwacom --set "Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Finger touch" Touch off`

Comment: I have the exact same problem with the Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch CTH-460, and the same experience with ScrollDistance (which is not a threshord as the docs claim) and Threshold (which doesn't seem to do anything), on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the initial lag / delay we're experiencing when trying to scroll using the two finger scroll gesture is due to a bug in xf86-input-wacom.

The parameter for controlling the scroll threshold is not exposed at all. Version 0.27.0 of xf86-input-wacom should be fixed (fix was pushed in September of this year). Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is still running 0.23.0.

Read http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/bugs/218/ for more details.

With regard to your touchpad sensitivity question I have no answer.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you want to adjust are Threshold and ScrollDistance.  Try setting both at the extremes (say, 5 and 100) to understand the effect of each, then adjust them to your liking.

Examples:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Finger touch" Threshold 50
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Finger touch" ScrollDistance 100
```

As far as the delay, that's something that bothers me a lot because I'm using an Intuos Pen & Touch as a mouse replacement, so I understand where you're coming from.  I don't think the ScrollDistance is functioning as described in the documentation, because it sounds like it's supposed to adjust the delay you mention.  In reality, however, it seems to adjust the distance required to scroll a certain amount on the screen.

The result is a low ScrollDistance acts very sensitive and allows you to scroll very quickly, but it still has that initial delay, so you might scroll through 100 pages before the action is completed.  For now the best compromise seems to be to adjust ScrollDistance very high (I use 100), so scrolling doesn't cause you to lose your place on the page.

Edit:  You may also want to make sure that your touch input Mode is set to Relative instead of Absolute.  This makes it function like a trackpad, whereas Absolute maps the entire screen to the tablet surface, amplifying any movements since the screen is so much larger than the tablet.

Example:

```
    xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Finger touch" Mode Relative
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, `Threshold` does not seem to change anything, from 1 to 50 to 100. `ScrollDistance` seems to impact the scrollspeed, not the delay before the scrolling starts. And not even the `Mode` seems to change anything, although your explanation makes total sense. I know I am using the correct Wacom string, because `Touch` (on or off) works normally.